# Visual Studio is not autocompleating html attrinbutes like id, class, hreff

Tags: visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio version 1.74.2 and it is not auto-completing attributes.

I have used many extensions like intellisence, Auto Close Tag, HTML CSS Support.

Comment: Do those extensions have any affect on your VS experience? Are you naming files with proper extensions?

Comment: Visual studio or visual studio code?

Answer (score 0):

look at the emmet configuration.

Go to settings, and type "emmet".

Example : Normally in your html you just have to type "link" and press <kbd>enter</kbd>